# Confusion | Redux saga does not throw any errors when API request fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I have a saga:

```
function* sagaOne() {
   try {
      yield all(users.map((user) => call(sagaTwo, user));
      console.log('test'); // being called even if the promise above rejected!
   } catch (error) {
     // stuff
   }
}
```

saga above calls saga below in `yield all` effect.

```
function* sagaTwo() {
   try {
      yield call(api); // some api call that fails
   } catch (error) {
     // stuff
   }
}
```

### My problem: the console.log in sagaOne is called even if api request fails!

Why does this happen? Even if api throws 422 error and `sagaTwo` throws an error, the `sagaOne` continues the flow and does not catch the error. Why?!

Edit: Im using axios for http requests

Comment: Are you throwing the error from sagaTwo?

Comment: @Siddharth what do you mean

Comment: You're trying to catch the same error twice, either remove the catch from sagaTwo or throw the error from its catch so that sagaOne can catch it again.

Comment: @Siddharth thanks, thats a good point. consider adding an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to catch the same error twice, either remove the catch from sagaTwo or throw the error from its catch so that sagaOne can catch it again.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal try catch behaviour - you are already catching the error i.e. you are handling the error so code execution resumes.

So, either remove `sagaTwo` catch block or after handling/logging error in catch block, throw a `new Error` in catch block. With this you won't see the log `test` printed

[see demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/saga-try-catch-8e1br?file=/index.js)